# Dependencies used to compile PCL can not be found when compiling something dependent on PCL

Tags: cmake, point-cloud-library

I am trying to build [treeseg](https://github.com/apburt/treeseg) which requires PCL.

I have successfully compiled PCL from source (yay!) but when I try and build treeseg the compiler can not find any of the packages that PCL has already used e.g. flann

Here is the `CMakeLists.txt` (I have edited so it finds PCL)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(treeseg)

set(PCL_DIR "/home/users/pwilkes/opt/pcl-pcl-1.10.0/build") # my edit
find_package(PCL 1.10 REQUIRED)
#find_package(Armadillo 9.8 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/riegl)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/riegl)

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
        if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/riegl/libscanifc-mt.so")
                add_executable(rxp2pcd ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rxp2pcd.cpp)
                target_link_libraries(rxp2pcd treeseg scanifc-mt)
        endif()
        else()  
                message(WARNING "rxp executables not building because either RIEGL libs/headers not found, or not a compatible OS.")
endif()
```

The truncated output from `cmake`

```
>     CMake Warning at /home/users/pwilkes/opt/pcl-pcl-1.10.0/build/PCLConfig.cmake:257
> (find_package):
>       By not providing "FindFLANN.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
>       asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "FLANN", but
>       CMake did not find one.
>     
>       Could not find a package configuration file provided by "FLANN" with any of
>       the following names:
>     
>         FLANNConfig.cmake
>         flann-config.cmake
```

My question is, why can PCL find these dependencies and treeseg can not?

Trying to compile on RHEL. flann etc. installed via conda.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with it now.

Answer (score 0):

So, in my case, it was because I never ran `make install`. When I did that, it created a `pcl-1.9/Modules` directory full of files like `FindFLANN.cmake`. Then I just set `PCL_DIR` and good to go.